# java.lang.ClassCastException: com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsFederatedQueueConnectionFactory cannot be cast to javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory

Tags: java, lookup

I am encountering the below exception when trying to look up for the JNDI context, although a similar question was already answered on this site referring the missing `tibjms.jar` from the class path to be the root cause.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsFederatedQueueConnectionFactory cannot be cast to javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory
at com.xxx.host.tibco.ConnectionHandler$JMSConnectionFactory.<init>(ConnectionHandler.java:337)
at com.xxx.host.tibco.ConnectionHandler.init(ConnectionHandler.java:94)
at com.xxx.host.tibco.ConnectionHandler.<init>(ConnectionHandler.java:84)
at com.xxx.host.tibco.ConnectionHandler.getInstance(ConnectionHandler.java:63)
at com.xxx.productOne.host.HostGetMemberBalanceRequest.doDecision(HostGetMemberBalanceRequest.java:42)
at com.audium.server.voiceElement.DecisionElementBase.service(DecisionElementBase.java:386)
at com.audium.server.controller.Controller.goToDecision(Controller.java:2857)
at com.audium.server.controller.Controller.goToElement(Controller.java:2687)
at com.audium.server.controller.Controller.continueCall(Controller.java:2511)
at com.audium.server.controller.Controller.goToElement(Controller.java:2742)
at com.audium.server.controller.Controller.continueCall(Controller.java:2511)
at com.audium.server.controller.Controller.doPost(Controller.java:733)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:879)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:81)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

In addition to this, I have the same piece of code working fine in another server with exactly same version/no. of libraries in TOMCAT.

Here is the code snippet of how the context is being looked up:

```
InitialContext iniCtx;
        try {
            iniCtx = new InitialContext(oProperties);
            PoolableObjectFactory objectFactory = new JMSConnectionFactory(iniCtx);
            this.pool = new GenericObjectPool(objectFactory);
            createQueues(iniCtx);
            singleton = this;
            System.out.println("Connection Handler is initialized");
        } catch (NamingException ne) {
            ne.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Any help in trouble-shooting is highly appreciated.

Comment: Try to replicate the problem in a small, self contained project.
Pasting 1 line of a stack trace with no code isn't going to get you much interest. Follow these guidelines: http://sscce.org/

Comment: This cannot be the case. If same piece of code is working in one server and not in other, then mostly likely cause is the mis- configuration. If everything is similar and has no difference, then there is no reason for contrasting behaviours.

Comment: I cannot rule out any changes between these two servers, however all i have verified is the exactly same set of libraries are ported from a working server to a newly configured server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problems like this are always one class (javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory in this case) loaded by different class loaders. Often, but not always, different classloader means different location from where the class was loaded. The location from where the class was loaded in turn is easy to figure out in debugger

```
javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
```

and

```
connectionFactory.getSuperclass()..
```

If the locations are different in most cases the reason gets clear imediately.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the class is loaded twice by different classloaders

Comment: Yes! I just found that the jms.jar was by default available in WEBINF folder and i had copied again in common/lib. Removing one of them solved the issue..